# config.ini file is overriden by update where and how to keep user defined variables

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We get the path of a file from user and keep it in config.ini to start eclipse. But when we update we see that config.ini file is overriden and we loose the information we got and saved in config.ini File.

Where should I use to keep user parameters. Is it possbile to keep a configuration parameter not overriden in config.ini file after an update ? (For example I want to keep a certain key-value pair.) If not how do you prefer to keep user parameters and where ?

Comment: Where is this path coming from? Is this something configured in a plugin?

Comment: It is a license file path asked by the program at the beginning ? We prompt a dialog for browsing to the path of the file and then save it at config.ini but that config.ini file is overriden after update !?

Comment: Perhaps the 'eclipse.ini' (or the equivalent for your RCP).

Comment: How can we read properties from eclipse.ini ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> If not how do you prefer to keep user parameters and where ?

Store them in the user's home directory.

Comment: We wanted to make eclipse directory portable so that a copy paste can make an easy solution to move the folder to a different computer. So that user does not need to copy the extra file in user's home directory.

Comment: I suspect I am simply missing something, but why not just store them in the workspace like all the other preferences? Otherwise, how about writing a file next to eclipse.exe