# PDE Root Files : how to export a file in eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm

At this link it tell about root files: I simply put

root = file:README.txt

at build.properties of the plugin but it didn't work. What else I need to configure.

It says at this link ( http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpde_feature_generating_build.htm ) root is only valid at feauture. So what should I do create a feature and do this at its build.properties ? What will happen to my plugins ? Do I need to add my plugins and the new feature at .product file ?

Comment: Hi, you never commented or responded to the last time you asked a very similar question. Can you explain why or why not using the user home directory is good/bad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694437/config-ini-file-is-overriden-by-update-where-and-how-to-keep-user-defined-variab

Comment: We look for a solution like config.ini created at eclipse plugin development environment and exported to the user product.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835247/how-to-add-files-to-the-eclipse-rcp-application-root-directory-application-type using root files looks to be a solution but any idea about how to use root files ?

Comment: OK, this is definitely getting somewhere (although you have completely re-written the question, it may be more visible if you ask an entirely new question as a new question on SO, but I am not sure...).

Answer (score 0):

> So what should I do create a feature and do this at its build.properties ?

Yes, Have you tried this?

You should have a feature project that references all the plugins in your product and the other features you depend on.

Comment: We decided not to use features at the moment. But I think this is possible via features ? Can't we do this without features only in plugins build.properties?

Comment: OK, if you decide not to use features, despite features being how you accomplish this, I am not sure how I can help, from the help you have linked in your question "It is possible to include a feature solely for the purpose of contributing rootfiles. If this "rootfile" feature does not specify a "bin.includes" property in its build.properties file, then it will not be included in the final build results, but its contributed rootfiles will be.
" - but I have not tried this